# RichEditBox - "Delayed" resize behavior on window resize - Doesn't "attach" to the top or bottom of Grid cell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, richeditbox

I have searched far and wide for an answer on this and have come up short. I am using Universal Windows 10 (UWP) and C# in Visual Studio 2015 to build a basic text editor to mirror the functionality of Notepad.exe as practice and I'm running into an annoying display problem/quirk.

I have a Grid with 2 rows. The top row is a horizontal `StackPanel` with buttons and the bottom is a `RichEditBox`. Everything displays fine.. except when the `RichEditBox` has keyboard focus (which I pretty much make sure is always) and I resize the window vertically, the `RichEditBox` (and its green border) resizes differently than its Grid container. When I pull the window down to resize, the border of the `RichEditBox` "detaches" on the top and bottom and quickly slides back up (and down) to fill the grid. In the process the text jitters around while this animation is taking place. Note: this does NOT happen when I resize horizontally. (image link below it won't let me embed the pic)

[image: Unwanted resize behavior]

It's not the end of the world but it looks unprofessional and there must be a way to anchor the `RichEditBox` vertically so it always fills the grid row completely and doesn't pull apart from its container when I resize. I tried all of the properties on the `Grid.Row`, the `RichEditBox` and its built in `ScrollViewer` that I thought could possibly have anything to do with this and no luck. Using the `VerticalAlignment = Top` causes the `RichEditBox` to no longer fill the grid row vertically (unless I fill it with text of course). I also put the `RichEditBox` inside of a `ScrollViewer` instead of using its built in `ScrollViewer` and it did the same behavior.

Here is my XAML:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="0"  Background="Azure" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False">

        <Button x:Name="FileButton" Content="File" Click="MenuButtonClicked" Padding="3,1"  Background="Azure">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New" Click="NewClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open..." Click="OpenClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save" Click="SaveClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save As..." Click="SaveAsClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Close" Click="CloseClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit" Click="ExitClicked" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="EditButton" Content="Edit" Click="MenuButtonClicked" Padding="3,1"  Background="Azure">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Undo" Click="UndoClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Cut" Click="CutClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Copy" Click="CopyClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Paste" Click="PasteClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Clear" Click="ClearClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Date/Time" Click="DateTimeClicked" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Select All" Click="SelectAllClicked" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="FormatButton" Content="Format" Click="MenuButtonClicked" Padding="3,1"  Background="Azure">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                    <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Word Warp" Click="WordWrapToggled" IsChecked="True"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="HelpButton" Content="Help" Click="MenuButtonClicked" Padding="3,1" Background="Azure">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="About" Click="AboutClicked" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <RichEditBox x:Name="MainTextBox"

        FontFamily="Consolas" 
        FontSize="14" 
        Grid.Row="1"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"

        IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        TabIndex="0"

        ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"

        KeyDown="TabKeyDown"
        Paste="ContentPasted"  />

</Grid>
```

Does anyone know how to make this behave the way I want it to?

I'm grateful for any help that anyone can give.

Comment: That's a good one, seems to be unique to RichEditBox, may be a bug. +1

Comment: Hmm.. Chris, if that were the case is there some place I could submit it as a potential bug? I haven't been able to find any other projects out there yet that use a RichEditBox in such a simplified way to compare my code to or to see if they get the same behavior..

Comment: Ya it would be [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) but I'm not sure exactly where you would plop it. If I can find time I'll dig in to it later and see if we can't find the culprit or at least a workaround. I tried a couple of my normal go-to workarounds for things like that with no luck but admittedly I didn't get a lot of time with it. I was hoping one of the MS folks here would chime in and teach us something new. There's some pretty sharp people on here that might see it also still.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you get a chance to look at it that would be awesome, if not then I'll just keep looking and wait to see if anyone else knows what's going on.